# Динамическое подключение к бд Laravel

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, postgresql, сессия

Я пытаюсь реализовать через middleware динамическое соединение с бд.
(добавлю: будет существовать около 200 подключений к бд. Каждое подключение, может быть, отдельным сервером. Структура бд будет одна и та же, будут меняться сами данные)

Успешно приходят данные, я заменяю их в config('database.connections.name)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возникает ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я выяснил эта ошибка возникает из-за удалении сессии. Уходит запрос на удаление сессии в бд, имея при этом старое подключение [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переменная $this - имеет старое подключение, но если я запрашиваю модель, она берется из нового подключения.

Если я в middleware убираю **DB::purge('tr_archive');**

Тогда запрос уходит, авторизация прошла успешно.
Но сессия не сохраняется в базе данных, и на следующий запрос возвращается 401, необходимо авторизоваться

Так же пытался добавить новое подключение к бд и к session.connection, ошибка та же, что и на втором скриншоте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так инициируйте другое подключение, зачем пытаться соединять два в одно?

Comment: @Николай, разве есть разница? На первом скриншоте, делал "dynamic_connection", результат тот же

Comment: @Николай, так же пытался изменить соединение для сессии. Все равно не помогло

Comment: Я подразумевал создание и использование другого объекта, а не наследование у первого

Comment: @Николай, сейчас не совсем понимаю о чем речь, можно, пожалуйста, подробнее. Создать новый объект SessionManager?

Comment: Вполне можете использовать [Config::set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085131/laravel-connect-to-databases-dynamically) для обновления вашего конфигурационного файла database.php.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, так я и использую это первый скриншот

Answer (score 0):

**app/config/database.php**

```
return array(

    'default' => 'mysql',

    'connections' => array(

        # Primary/Default database connection
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host1',
            'database'  => 'database1',
            'username'  => 'user1',
            'password'  => 'pass1'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        # Secondary database connection
        'mysql2' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host2',
            'database'  => 'database2',
            'username'  => 'user2',
            'password'  => 'pass2'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Запрос ко второму подключению:

```
$users = DB::connection('mysql2')->select(...);
```

Comment: Спасибо, но такое не пойдёт. Потому что будет около 200 подключений к бд. 1 подключение = 1 организация. И править всё 200 конфигов не хочется, потому что сервера могут быть разными. Сейчас существует мастер бд, где хранится информация о подключении к бд, и дефолтная, которую я пытаюсь заменить

Comment: Так мастер производит репликации автоматически. И тогда выходит что двойное подключение совсем не имеет смысла. Или я чего-то не понимаю

Comment: Пользователь будет иметь только одно подключение. Но при авторизации он сможет выбирать к какой организации ему подключиться, дальше уже с ней взаимодействовать.

Comment: На вашем месте я бы использовал скрипт создания нового файла конфигурации по выбранным условиям. Других вариантов не вижу

Answer (score 0):

Получилось разобраться с этой ситуации. Сессия почему-то не может переподключиться к новому соединению. Изначально мы использовали две бд.

1. использовали для различных метрик, и базовые ларавеловские таблицы
2. база данных приложения. Там всё таблицы, для всех моделей. Это подключение должно изменяться.

И вот у нас сессия хранилась во второй базе. Когда мы меняли подключение, то система не видела старое соединение с базой.
Мы перенесли таблицу сессию ларавеь в первое соединение. Теперь всё работает.